# mysql select query optimization

Tags: mysql, performance, select, query-optimization

I have two table testa & testb.

```
CREATE TABLE `testa` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `testb` (
  `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aid1` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aid2` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aid3` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Currently I am running below query for retrieving all rows where id in testa table matches with any columns of aid1,aid2,aid3 in tableb. The query is retreiving acurate result but it is taking minimum 30 seconds to execute which is too much. I have also tried to optimise my query using UNION but failed to do so.

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.name, b.id 
FROM testb b 
INNER JOIN testa a ON b.aid1 = a.id OR b.aid2 = a.id OR b.aid3 = a.id ;
```

How do i optimize my query so it's total execution time is within 2-3 seconds?

Thanks in advance...

Result of EXPLAIN:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  b   ALL idx_aid1,idx_aid2,idx_aid3  (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  10940   
1   SIMPLE  a   ALL PRIMARY (NULL)  (NULL)  (NULL)  7512    Using where; Using join buffer
```

Comment: From comments to other answers, it would be more helpful if you could show some sample data of what you are trying to get (without exposing actual privacy type information). Also, clarify what intended content of "A" vs "B" table.  If we know the context of this otherwise abstract, it too might help in alternative solution.

Comment: How many rows are in table testa and testb, respectively?

Comment: testa - 7600 & testb - 11000

Comment: One more question: does it run fast and use indexes if you join using just one field out of 3, like aid1? In other words, does `EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT a.id, a.name, b.name, b.id FROM testb b INNER JOIN testa a ON b.aid1 = a.id` show using indexes?

Comment: yes, It uses tha index idx_aid1. but when I use all three columns with OR it taking too much time.

Comment: I think I know what is happening now. Last question: is it possible for aid1, aid2 or aid3 to be NULL, and if yes, how big is probability that at least one of them is NULL in any given row of testb?

Comment: It is possible that all three has data or any of two / one column contains data.

Answer (score 4):

Because you permit for aid1, aid2, aid3 to be NULL (and apparently, they are mostly NULL per your explanation), your join condition is effectively not indexable.

Why? SQL expression `b.aid1 = a.id OR b.aid2 = a.id OR b.aid3 = a.id`
evaluates to NULL if any of aid1, aid2 or aid3 is NULL, and this is why MySQL planner does not show using an index.

Solution: do not use NULLs for aid1, aid2, aid3. Instead, invent special id (say 0) which is guaranteed to not exist in testa.
Then, make sure that testb.aid[123] are NOT NULL (and assign it to 0 where it was NULL before).

**EDIT**: Adding alternative approach to this problem.

You can also solve this problem if you can afford to change your schema by adding one more table. This new table will contain list of aid's you currently store in table testb, and testb will contain just one id linking to new table. This should be similar to what is explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412735/how-to-setup-sqlite-join-on-variable-column-data/13413130#13413130). Additional advantage to this is that you can permit arbitrary number of aid's (not just 3 as you have now).

Comment: I had updated my table and set 0 as default value of three columns and updated current data but still query taking too much time to execute.

Comment: Can you separate it into 3 independent queries by aid[123] and then `UNION ALL` all 3 of them?

Comment: As I had already specified in question that I had tried with UNION in query but I have parent query also if I use UNION my query executes with 13 tables including testa and testb. So I am not able to use UNION in my query.

Comment: Wait a minute! Parent query? If you hope to get any answer, you should explain everything you have. It's like going to doctor and not telling that you are taking some other drugs. If you want to keep data privacy - sure, but do not omit important details. Also, do note that I asked for `UNION ALL`, which is not the same as `UNION`.

Comment: Thanks for your help but sorry my friend I am not able to disclose my parent query. I am sure that this pary of query taking too much time to execute.

Comment: I have amended my answer to provide alternative way to solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the indexing that others have suggested, make sure you `ANALYZE` your tables so that the statistics on the tables are up-to-date.  If the statistics are wildly different from what's actually in the table, then the query planner will make bad choices.

Comment: I had already Analyzes both the tables and all stats are perfect.

Answer (score 0):

you should index on the following columns to avoid fulltable scan

```
  `aid1` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aid2` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aid3` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL,
```

if you want to alter the tables

```
ALTER TABLE testb ADD INDEX (aid1);
ALTER TABLE testb ADD INDEX (aid2);
ALTER TABLE testb ADD INDEX (aid3);
```

Comment: I had already added index on that column but not able to find much difference

Comment: can you post the result on this query `EXPLAIN SELECT a.id, a.name, b.name, b.id 
FROM testb b 
INNER JOIN testa a ON b.aid1 = a.id OR b.aid2 = a.id OR b.aid3 = a.id`

Answer (score 0):

Have You tried joining with `IN` instead of `OR`?

`SELECT a.id, a.name, b.name, b.id 
FROM testb b 
INNER JOIN testa a ON a.id IN (b.aid1, b.aid2, b.aid3) ;`

Comment: Still query taking too much time.

Comment: But is there any improvement?

Comment: No. It's taking more time to execute

Comment: Nice to know. This was just a suggestion(not tested).

Comment: Thanx for your suggestion and let me know if you find something interesting to solve this issue

Comment: Glad to help. P.S. Try combining stuff from all the answers.